# Skyrim how do i get rid of Serana

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the dawnguard main quest line and I had Serana as my follower. I got to the mission to go to the chantry of auriel to get auriels bow and whenever I got there I poured the water in and the door wouldn't open, making the quest impossible to complete.

Since its impossible to complete I can't dismiss Serana since I haven't finished the quest and I have requested a mod for skyrim special edition PS4 on Bethesda.net but no one has made it. If anyone knows how to fix this plese tell me how to get rid of her, I don't have the save to load back before I did the quest.

Comment: so, you are still stuck in that quest?

Comment: Likely reloading a previous save could help.

Comment: Yes I am, and I don't have a far enough save to load back to

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Touching_the_Sky), this is a common bug with the game. The Ewer cannot be poured into the basin, as for some reason, the game has already advanced the quest-line past that point, making the player unable to interact with the basin.

There are console commands to fix this, however as you mentioned, you're on PS4, slightly negating this solution. The easiest of solutions with the console is to use `TCL` to turn off player collision, and moving to where you need to go. Turn off `TCL` once through, and find the door that leads to the next cell. Serana would be with you at that point, and you can continue the quest.

Otherwise, the only other potential solution would be to reload a save that occurred before the quest was started. Consider this a lesson in making multiple saves over time!

Comment: How do I use console commands on ps4?

Comment: @Hey_Mama909 Unfortunately, as it stands, there is no mod to enable console commands on PS4/X1, nor is there any intention of there being such a mod. Pete Hines has explicitly stated that console commands run the risk of breaking your game/saves, and they're simply not allowed through Microsoft/Sony's approval process. As such, the solution of reloading a previous save is the only one that applies to your case. The console commands are more for is a PC player runs into this problem.

Comment: I can't load back to in though, save file is gone

Comment: Well then as i said, consider this a lesson in keeping multiple saves.

Comment: Isn't the data on the ps4 thought couldn't I do something to make it the most recent

Comment: No that's not how it works. I'm sorry, you're out of luck.